# How to set zend pagination for large data set?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I want to set pagination for large collection of data set say tens of thousands. 
If you fetch all data at once  performance will be slow. So I need a better approach:

In my controller I have the code as given:

```
    $result = $result = $this->fetchAll($this->select()
                                            ->where('id='.$id)
                                            ->order('date DESC'))->toArray();
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($data);
    $pageNumber = $this->_getParam('page');       
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pageNumber);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    $this->view->data = $paginator;
```

This code will fetch all database contents at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$select = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($sql);
$select->count($select);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator($select);
```

You can get more details from here:

[**Paginating data collection**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html)

Comment: not work, the query is built well but when i fetch data using foreach, data not showing.

_sorry i speak english not well_

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    $select = $this->select()->where('id='.$id)
                             ->order('date DESC');

    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select));
    $pageNumber = $this->_getParam('page');       
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($pageNumber);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    $this->view->data = $paginator;
```